# why is my flutter app's user-info page loosing the data stored when i restart the app? (fyi the data is getting stored in Firebase but not in the app)

Tags: flutter

i'm Trying to create a user-info page using flutter and i manage to store the info in the Firebase-cloud server which is good,but it looses the information in my app screen once i restart the app or navigate to another page,how do i make the info survive a restart? and can i add and retrieve the data at the same time with Firestore.instance.collection('userinfo').

[this is a screenshot of my app page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jv4Ej.jpg)

```
   class _UserInfoPageState extends State<UserInfoPage> {
  void _submitUserInfo(String userName, String address, String userPhone,
      String pincode, String state)

  {
    Firestore.instance.collection('userinfo').add({
      'username': userName,
      'Address': address,
      'user Phone no': userPhone,
      'pincode': pincode,
      'state': state,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell with that huge block of code. But I couldn't find anywhere in your code where you fetch the information from Firebase.

Any data that isn't saved on the device gets cleared when you close the app. So you will have to pull the data from Firebase to populate it, or you store it on the device(look into SharedPreferences).

If I missed something important in your code I apologize.

Comment: i am sorry the code to how i send the data to firebase was in the other page  the code is as below:
 
  
    Firestore.instance.collection('userinfo').add({
      'username': userName,
      'Address': address,
      'user Phone no': userPhone,
      'pincode': pincode,
      'state': state,
    });

Comment: @Ryan But how are you getting the data back when you load your app? thats the important part.

Comment: Firstly thanks a lot for your time, but i'm not able to understand how to get that data back?if i google on how to retrieve data from Firebase and i open the Firebase docs here  (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data) which is not answering my querry .

Comment: Have a look at this: https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore specifically the "get" part. Storing your data in firestore is just the first step. To actually use the data, you have to get it back from the server. It doesn't automatically come back to your app.